# Creating multipage PDF in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, pdf-generation, multipage

I am developing an application in which i have to create multi page PDF and email such PDF. The content which is to be converted to PDF contains text as well as some images. I have seen some posts regarding this, but could not glean too much from it. Will be greatful if any one can guide in this.

Thanx, regards.

Comment: Would be helpful to know what you've already tried, at what point you're stuck etc. You can't expect stackoverflow people to assemble a tailored guide for you ( as useful as it would be! ).

Comment: Hi,actually I had made multi Page Pdf before , but I have only created PDF using text only.This time I have to create a PDF using text as well as images also. I am stuck at this images part.

Comment: could you give me a sample to convvert a text in to pdf

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) which has a cloud-based document generator.  It can generate PDFs and stream them back to the iPad or send as email.  You upload a template to the cloud using the Docmosis web site, then you can generate documents from your iPad by sending a request (with data, images etc) to the Docmosis cloud.